# Is it possible to mix different fonts for different alphabets?

Tags: pdf, web, fonts

My use case is as such: my web application is only available in English and we are using the font Nunito. Some people write within the app with characters from other alphabets, but it works, I guess because the browser automatically changes the font. So for example if I write this, it works: γεια σας สวัสดี 你好 Helló ሰላም صباح الخير

But you can make a PDF export from my app, and I had to declare the font for the export, so of course now the characters not included in Nunito are replaced with blank rectangles.

I want the PDF export to display all the characters, and I know the font Noto is available in a lot of languages with different alphabets, but the thing is, as I said, our app is only available in English, so I cannot use a specific font depending on the selected language, and even if it was possible, that wouldn't fix the problem when mixing different alphabets.

So my question is: is there a single font that includes "a lot of" alphabets; or is there a way to load different fonts (such as all the Noto variants) and add a mechanism that chooses the best one for every character (something like a fallback from font to font, like I guess the browsers do)?

Comment: @KJ Thanks, indeed the universal solution sounds like a nightmare. I'm not sure what you mean in your last sentence, even if I load Noto Arabic, Noto Chinese, etc., how can I dynamically choose the right font for the right character if the user wrote something like "γεια σας สวัสดี 你好 Helló ሰላም صباح الخير"?

Comment: OK but when I have all the fonts, I'm supposed to detect in which language the characters are and apply a specific font for that specific part of the text?

Comment: If your app were a native Windows app, then there are DirectWrite APIs that can provide fallback fonts for a string. (There are probably similar APIs on MacOS/iOS or Android.) But in a web app, there's no equivalent API supported by browsers, and even if there were, different OS platforms would have different fonts. You'll need to implement your own fallback logic.

Comment: @PeterConstable So I have to detect the language (or languages) of a string and apply a specific font on each word? Is this even possible?

Comment: You don't have to detect the _language_. Font fallback implementations focus on the script or Unicode code point ranges of characters in a string. So, for example, if a string has Unicode characters U+0400 to U+04FF, those are Cyrillic script characters, and you can format those using a font that supports Cyrillic; or if the string has characters in the range U+AC00 to U+D7AF, those will be Korean Hangul characters, and a Hangul font can be used.

Comment: Thanks, so I've managed to detect the language based on unicode and apply the correct font (all from the Noto collection). Now of course it doesn't work perfectly because some languages have characters in common so choosing Chinese over Japanese may cause some problems, for example. Arabic doesn't render at all. And sometimes some characters aren't rendered or are strangely rendered / positioned within the text. I guess these problems are because of the PDF generator.